# Pivoting data with changing dates in Oracle 10G

Tags: sql, oracle10g, pivot

I am creating this view in Oracle 10G where I pivot based on a date column (while grouped by 2 others).  The issue is the months are going to change depending on the month we are in.  So for Month1 it will always be the first of the current month, Month2 will be the first of next month and so on.  The pivoting when I hardcoded the dates worked fine but now I need to make the dates relative, so I tried this code from [here](https://www.mandsconsulting.com/first-and-last-day-of-month-oracle-sql-syntax-examples/):

```
trunc((sysdate),'dd/mm/yy')
```

but I am receiving this error:

> ORA-01898: too many precision specifiers
>   01898. 00000 -  "too many precision specifiers"
>   *Cause:    While trying to truncate or round dates, extra data was found in the
>              date format picture
>   *Action:   Check the syntax of the date format picture and retry.

I also need it to move based on year.  So we are in November, when it gets to January I need it to move to 2018 and same next year.  Here is the total code:

```
    select FPC, FWHSE,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, trunc((sysdate),'dd/mm/yy'), QTY)) AS MONTH1,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-DEC-17', QTY)) AS MONTH2,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-JAN-18', QTY)) AS MONTH3,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-FEB-18', QTY)) AS MONTH4,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-MAR-18', QTY)) AS MONTH5,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-APR-18', QTY)) AS MONTH6,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-MAY-18', QTY)) AS MONTH7,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-JUN-18', QTY)) AS MONTH8,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-JUL-18', QTY)) AS MONTH9,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-AUG-18', QTY)) AS MONTH10,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-SEP-18', QTY)) AS MONTH11,
Max(DECODE(f.FFPD, '01-OCT-18', QTY)) AS MONTH12
from TBL_FORECAST_LATEST f
where FPC = '00002' and FWHSE = 'ROA'
GROUP BY f.FPC, f.FWHSE;
```

Comment: The solution for last and first days of the month in that link uses weird and less straightforward method. `TRUNC(sysdate,'MM')`  gives you first day and `LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)` gives you the last day of the month.

Comment: @KaushikNayak, thank you but then how do I get the first of next month, the first of the month after, etc.

Comment: I think I figured it out: trunc((ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, 1))

Comment: Use the combination of `add_months` and the above

Comment: thank you @KaushikNayak, I figured it out right before